# how to open multiple puppeteer instances without effecting it's speed

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, automation, puppeteer

so what happening to me is when i open 1 puppeteer instance it would go fast a but the more i open the more time it need to load the URL + fill information is that a normal thing ?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: More details are helpful. Are you running multiple instances of this script, or is it multiple browsers or pages? How many processes are you able to open before running into slowdowns? How many cores are on your computer? (etc). Thanks.

Comment: hello, thank you for you comment am  running multiple instances of the script , for example if i run 1 instance the loading time would be 1 sec , if 2 instances the instances would take 2 sec or so , i have 4 cored , 8 threads , corei7 7700hq thank you again

Comment: Cool, thanks. Could you use [puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster) instead? How about one process with multiple browsers?

Comment: well i used worker_threads and cluster dont know if that make a change but thanks i will check it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer

Performance of

1. multiple pupeteer instances
   and
2. running on the same machine
   and
3. testing a single application

is highly dependent on the performance of your machine (`4 cored , 8 threads , corei7 7700hq`)

On my local setup I could not run more than 10 parallel instances and the performance drop was noticeable the more instances I've launched.

## My Story

I have faced similar challenge, when I was trying to simulate multiple users using the same application in parallel.

**I know**: pupeteer (and/or) similar ui-test-automation tools are **not good tools for stresstesting** your application; or that: there are better tools for that.

Nevertheless, my case was:

1. Run "user-like" behavior
2. From the other end of the world
3. Collect `HAR` files - that represent network timings of the browser interacting with 10-20 different systems
4. Analyze the behavior

My approach was - maybe this helps you:

1. Create a puppeteer test
2. Enable headless running
3. Make it triggerable via `curl`
4. Dockerize it
5. Run the `docker` image on 10 different machines (`5-10` dockerized pupeteer tests/machine)
6. Trigger them all at once via `curl`

[image: plantuml pupeteer usage scenario]